# Internal server error 500 while sending data from react to Django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django

I am making a crop prediction system where user will send some data to backend and crop_prediction function will predict a crop and send it to frontend to display it.
I checked my views.py function it is working properly on Django rest framework.
But when sending data it is giving internal server error.
Please suggest any modification in my code.

My frontend code to send data

```
async function userDataHandler(userData) {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/Efarma/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
  }
```

Django views code:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from firebase import firebase
import numpy as np 
# from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParses
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import pickle
from efarma import config
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

def weather_fetch(city_name):
    """
    Fetch and returns the temperature and humidity of a city
    :params: city_name
    :return: temperature, humidity
    """
    api_key = config.weather_api_key
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"

    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()

    if x["cod"] != "404":
        y = x["main"]

        temperature = round((y["temp"] - 273.15), 2)
        humidity = y["humidity"]
        return temperature, humidity
    else:
        return None

@api_view(('POST','GET',))
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def crop_prediction(request):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        N = float(request.form['nitrogen'])
        P = float(request.form['phosphorous'])
        K = float(request.form['pottasium'])
        ph = float(request.form['ph'])
        rainfall = float(request.form['rainfall'])
        city = request.form.get("city")

        if weather_fetch(city) != None:
            temperature, humidity = weather_fetch(city)
            data = np.array([[N, P, K, temperature, humidity, ph, rainfall]])
            my_prediction = pickle.load(open('cropRecommendationBackend\\model\\model.pkl','rb'))
            final_prediction=my_prediction.predict(data)
            value=final_prediction[0]
            firebase =firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://e-farma-5dc42-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/')
            result=firebase.get(final_prediction,None)
            return Response(result)
        
        else: return Response("Some error occured")
    else: return Response("Some error occured")
```

Settings.py file:-

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6o=k+7ec442!!jxbtwu9q-+fb%l=1t6o0z2f!(-qpm1!4a@pl^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'efarma',
    'rest_framework',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
     'http://localhost:3000'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cropRecommendationBackend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cropRecommendationBackend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: What does your log say? It should give you an indication as to what is causing the error.

Comment: It says:-POST http://localhost:8000/Efarma/ 500 (Internal Server Error)